# Understanding conversion of frequency-warped signal and its orignal signal

Tags: audio, frequency, allpass

I'm reading an article [Frequency-Warped Signal Processing for Audio Applications](https://www.aes.org/e-lib/browse.cfm?elib=12039) which is talking about frequency warping. An open access version of this artical is available [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Aki-Haermae/publication/236340567_Frequency-Warped_Signal_Processing_for_Audio_Applications/links/02e7e52c6abe318340000000/Frequency-Warped-Signal-Processing-for-Audio-Applications.pdf).

Say a signal or impulse response $s(n)$, its $z$ transform is given by
$$
S(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s(n)z^{-n} \tag{1}
$$

The frequency warping procedure can be interpreted as a bilinear transform determined by the mapping
$$
z^{-1} \to \widetilde{z}^{-1} = \frac{z^{-1}-\lambda}{1-\lambda z^{-1}} \tag{2}
$$
and its inverse mapping
$$
\widetilde{z}^{-1} \to {z}^{-1} = \frac{\widetilde{z}^{-1}+\lambda}{1+\lambda \widetilde{z}^{-1}} \tag{3}
$$

One can write a warped representation for Eq. (1) by
$$
S(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} w(k) \widetilde{z}^{-k} \tag{4}
$$

where $w(k)$ are the samples of a corresponding warped impulse response. Natually Eqs. (1) and (4) should be equal, that is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s(n)z^{-n} =  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} w(k) \left({\frac{z^{-1}-\lambda}{1-\lambda z^{-1}}}\right)^{k} \tag{5}
$$

Further more, one may use Eq. (3) to map the whole equation to the warped $z$ domain. This yields
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s(n)\left(\frac{\widetilde{z}^{-1}+\lambda}{1+\lambda \widetilde{z}^{-1}} \right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} w(k) \widetilde{z}^{-k} \tag{6}
$$

What confused me is the authors claimed that

> In the time domain, the right-hand side of Eq. (5) is a $w(n)$-weighted superposition of the impulse responses of the output of the all-pass chain and therefore a method to synthesize a time-domain signal $s(n)$ from its warped counterpart $w(k)$. Correspondingly, the time-domain representation of the left-hand side of Eq. (6) gives a method to compute a warped signal $w(n)$ from the original signal as a superposition of impulse responses of a chain of all-pass filters.

My questions are:

1. What are "the impulse responses of the output of the all-pass chain" and "impulse responses of a chain of all-pass filters" respectively?
2. How to implement the computation of the warped signal from the orignal signal, such as by MATLAB?

---

Edit:

Thanks for Hilmar's great answer.

I've reproduce the example using the following code:

```
fs = 48e3;
fir = [0.5, 0, -0.5];
p = 0.9;
b = [-p, 1];
a = [1, -p];
x = [1; zeros(1000, 1)]; % delta
xn1 = filter(b, a, x);   % x[n-1]
xn2 = filter(b, a, xn1); % x[n-2]
y = fir(1) * x + fir(2) * xn1 + fir(3) * xn2; % impluse response
```

But I found that when $p>0$ I got the same results as shown in the answer. Am I missing something?

---

Edit again:

OK, I should use the inverse mapping
$$
\tilde{H}(\tilde{z}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty h(n) \left(\frac{\tilde{z}^{-1}+\lambda}{1+\lambda \tilde{z}^{-1}}\right)^n
$$

Thus the all-pass filter should be

```
b = [p, 1];
a = [1, p];
```

and I got the same results as Hilmar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frequency warping based on a conformal mapping in the z-planes that maps the unit circle onto itself.

The transfer function of this mapping is

$$A(z) = \frac{-p+z^{-1}}{1-pz^{-1}}$$

That is indeed an all pass filter, i.e. $|A(\omega)| = 1$. It has pole at $p$ and a zero at $1/p$. It's stable and causal as long as the pole is inside the unit circle, i.e. $|p| < 1$.

Let's look at a 3 tap FIR filter. The difference equation is

$$y[n] = b_0x[n] + b_1x[n-1] + b_2x[n-2]$$ and the transfer function

$$H(z) = b_0 + b_1z^{-1}+ b_2z^{-2}$$

The FIR structure is a chain of identical unit delays where the output is a weighted sum from each node in the chain.

[image]

The idea behind frequency warping is to replace the delays  with first order allpass filters. That makes the overall contraption an IIR filter, but it maintains the overall structure of an FIR filter. Instead of a chain of identical delays you have a chain of identical all pass filters. The output in both cases is a weighted sum of each node in the chain.

Warping maintains the overall shape of the filter (peaks and dips, etc.) but it moves it to different frequencies. Depending on which direction you warp you stretch the frequencies. If the pole is negative, the features will move towards lower frequencies and vice versa. While an FIR has all the poles at $z=0$, the warped FIR has all the poles at $z=p$. In fact, the unit delay is just one special case of a all pass filter: if you pop in $p = 0$ into the all pass transfer function, it becomes a unit delay.

Here is a quick example using the worlds simplest bandpass filter `h = [0.5 0 -0.5]` at a 48 kHz sample rate and warping it with three different poles.

[image]

Without warping the "feature" of this filter is at a very high frequency, since the impulse response is so short. However with warping we can move this across the entire audio spectrum and can do something useful even below 100Hz which typically would require 1000s of taps at 48 kHz.

> What are "the impulse responses of the output of the all-pass chain" and "impulse responses of a chain of all-pass filters" respectively?

These are signals at the nodes in the block diagram above. For an FIR it's the in/outputs of the delays, for the warped FIR it's the in/outputs of the all passes

> How to implement the computation of the warped signal from the original signal, such as by MATLAB?

You can't really warp a signal. You can only warp the impulse response of a system resulting a warped filter. The implementation is easy enough

1. Write an FIR filter from scratch (don't use any build in functions)
2. Replace every delay in your code with a first order all pass filter

Technically you could calculate the cascaded difference equation and/or the zeros and implement it as a regular IIR filter, but it turns out sticking with cascaded first order all-pass filter is both the most efficient and easiest way to implement it.

## Update

Added on more example with positive warping

[image]

Comment: Most probably I'm missing something, but it looks like it's just an adjustable bandpass. Since the signal can't be warped, wouldn't a simple IIR be an equivalent, instead of the whole FIR+IIR allpass?

Comment: I just used a bandpass as a simple example. Warped FIR filters can be very useful of you have a more complicated amplitude and phase response. Of course you can always do the same with IIR filter, a warped FIR filter is after all just a special case of an IIR filter. However IIR design for with good resolution at very low frequency (which is typically required in audio) is VERY difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Hilmar! I've reproduced your example but I found that when $p>0$ I got the same results as you shown. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Hilmar "*IIR design for with good resolution at very low frequency (which is typically required in audio) is VERY difficult*" -- true, I didn't consider this part.

Comment: @DSPnovice. With $p > 0$ the peak of the bandpass moves up in frequency. It it doesn't than something might be wrong with your code or math. See updated answer for $p = +0.5$

Comment: Sorry Hilmar. I meant the result of $p=0.5$ in my code is the same as your result of $p=-0.5$.